# Unable to submit form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to submit my form named 'vform' by using javascript and ajax.Here
Button named 'show' is being used to show the 'div' containing form named vform and that form calls codevalidate function and there it submits the form using some ajax code..Where i am getting error is vform.submit().Here's the html and js code(I know error is in if condition but do not know where)

**html:**

```
<button id="show" onClick="javascript:codefield(); return false";>Apply for Discount</button>
            <div id="apply" style="display:none">Voucher code<br>
            <form id="vform" name="vform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:codevalidate(); return false;" >
            <input type="text" name="code" id="code"><br>
            <span id="error" style="color:red"></span><br>
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="apply" id="btn" ></form>
            </div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function codevalidate()
{

if(document.getElementById('code').value!=="")
{
$.post("couponajax.php",{code:$("#code").val()},
    function(data)
    {   
        if(data=='1')
        {
            //alert("success");
            vform.submit();
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="You have entered a wrong code!";
            return false;
        }

    });

}
else
{
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Code can't be empty!";
return false;
}

return false;
```

}

codefield function is just displaying the div on onclick event and ajax call is just checking whether the code exists in database or not..if exists returns 1 else 0.
The problem is alert message is being displayed but form is not being submitted. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById("vform").submit();`

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working yet.(if I use vform.submit() outside the if condition then it is working.)

Comment: can you `log` or `alert` the `data` returned by `post` request?

Comment: Yes alert message (success) is working.

Comment: `action` attribute of your `form` is empty. why is that? that can be a reason. and btw on which `browser` you are testing your code?

Comment: If action attribute would have created the error then it would have never submitted the form..I mean in case I write form.submit() outside if condition it gets submit?why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing jquery selector.

Try to replace

```
vform.submit();
```

with

```
$("#vform").submit();
```

or you can call submit button click event like

```
$("#btn").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the form.

Try changing;

```
vform.submit();
```

To:

```
$("#vform").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, works for me.

```
document.getElementById("vform").submit();
```

Comment: For me vform.submit is also working but not in if condition. I used if(isset($_POST['btn'])){echo "form submitted";}..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.forms["vform"].submit();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to submit form with code.

Just call validation function and control submit flow with preventDefault function.

```
var codevalidate = function(e) {
    if (!validationCode) { // if validation code didn't pass
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting
    }
}
// register callback that will be called when user submits form
document.getElementById("vform").addEventListener('onsubmit', codevalidate);
```

That way form will be submitted by user only if validation pass.

Also check if your `data` is actually returning '1' by calling `console.log(data);`

Form will be submitted to the current address if action is empty, is that ok?

Comment: I am using the post values on the same page..so yes that's ok. and yes the data is actually returning 1.The problem is form.submit(); code is working if i am using it outside if condition..i don know why..(btw thanks a lot:) )

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that:

`action` attribute of your `form` element is empty. So it is being submitted but to the same page from which it is calling the `.submit()` method.

so you should specify `action` attribute first of all like:

```
<form id="vform" name="vform" action="vfrom_submit.php" method="post" 
  onsubmit="javascript:codevalidate(); return false;" >
        .....
</form>
```

Also try changing

```
vform.submit();
```

to:

```
$("#vform").submit();
//OR
// document.getElementById("vform").submit();
// Although vform.submit() can also work.
```

Hope it helps, cheers :)!

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("vform").submit();
```

Update:

Try removing "return false;" from onsubmit attribute and remove "vform.submit();" from the if condition  as well.